# QML: Autoresize the TextInput

Tags: qt, fonts, qml, font-size

`Text` type has this nice feature `fontSizeMode`, which tries to fit the font size to the actual size of the visual component. So that when I set the font size to 20 and I resize the window so this font size is too big, it automatically lowers the font size.

```
Text {
          text: qsTr("Text")
          font.pointSize: 20
          fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
     }
```

Now I wanted to use this functionality with the `TextInput` type, but there is no `fontSizeMode` available. So my question is, how can I achieve the same functionality with `TextInput`? Now, when the font size is set and I downsize the window, the string in the `TextInput` is cut in half like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can scale the element down to constrain it to a specific width:

```
  Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 50
    color: "red"
    TextInput {
      anchors.centerIn: parent
      font.pointSize: 20
      text: "test"
      scale: Math.min(1, parent.width / contentWidth)
      Rectangle {
        color: "white"
        anchors.fill: parent
        z: -1
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem isn't the width, there is `clip` for that. My problem is the height. I added an image to the question where it's shown.

Comment: Just scale according to the available height then.

Comment: If you mean just rewriting width to height, it didn't help, the behaviour is still the same.

Comment: It's probably because in the example provided by dtech, the `Rectangle` has a fixed width, not bound on the window size. If you change the `height` to 20 you will see that the scale works. You should bind the scale or the container size to the actual window size.

Comment: @T.Poe - the concept is universal, if the number exceeds the limit, scale it down by the number/limit ratio. Just plug it into your code. It's just programmers here, no psychics that magically know your code and the exact format of the solution you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I sticked with this solution. Bind the `font.pixelSize` property to the parent height. Although I'm not sure if it is 100% correct, it does exactly what I want. If there is some problem about it, please make me know.

```
 Text {
      text: qsTr("Text")
      font.pixelSize: 0.1 * parent.height
 }
```

Comment: He asked about TextInput, not Text.